# How I can test that one Laravel job dispatches an another one on testing?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, assert, jobs

I have the following Laravel Worker:

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

use App\Lobs\AnotherJob;

class MyWorker implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable;
    use InteractsWithQueue;
    use Queueable;

    public function handle(): void
    {
       AnotherJob::dispatch();
    }
}
```

And I want to unit-test that my job dispatches the `AnotherJob`:

```
namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase;

class TestMyWorker extends TestCase
{
  public function testDispachesAnotherJob()
  {
    MyWorker::dispatchNow();
    //Assert that AnotherJob is dispatched
  }
}
```

Do you know how I can seert that `AnotherJob::dispatch()` is actually be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has [queue mocks/fakes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mocking#queue-fake) that will handle that. Try this:

```
namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue;
use App\Jobs\MyWorker;
use App\Jobs\AnotherJob;

class TestMyWorker extends TestCase
{
  public function testDispachesAnotherJob()
  {
    Queue::fake();
    MyWorker::dispatchNow();
    Queue::assertPushed(MyWorker::class);
    Queue::assertPushed(AnotherJob::class);
  }
}
```

Comment: But according to similar question this approach does not work: 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/why-i-am-unable-to-assert-that-a-job-has-not-been-dispatched